# Vector Field Divergence calculation with Fourier Sine Transform

Tags: c, matlab, fft, differential-equations, fftw

Given the definition of [DST-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_sine_transform#DST-I), [DCT-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#DCT-I), their relation to the DFT ([1],[2]) as well as the differentiation [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Partial_differential_equations) of the DFT;

> [1]: "A DST-I is exactly equivalent to a DFT of a real sequence that is odd around the zero-th and middle points, scaled by 1/2. For example, a DST-I of N=3 real numbers (a,b,c) is exactly equivalent to a DFT of eight real numbers (0,a,b,c,0,-c,-b,-a) (odd symmetry), scaled by 1/2. "

> [2]: "The DCT-I is exactly equivalent (up to an overall scale factor of 2), to a DFT of 2N-2 real numbers with even symmetry. For example, a DCT-I of N=5 real numbers abcde is exactly equivalent to a DFT of eight real numbers abcdedcb (even symmetry), divided by two."

How do we go about calculating the Divergence of a velocity field on a square domain (with DST-I boundary condition)?

.
.
.

My unsuccessful tackle with this problem thus far:

I generate a 2D Function, similar to [0,a,b,c,0,-c,-b,-a] with Matlab:

```
N=8;
x5 =  linspace(3, -3,N+1); x5 = x5(1:N);
[X1,X2] = ndgrid(x5, x5); 
Z= sin(X1) .* sin(X2);
```

The resulting, somewhat hand-modified output look like:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   a   b   c   0   -c  -b  -a
0   b   e   f   0   -f  -e  -b
0   c   f   g   0   -g  -f  -c
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   -c  -f  -g  0   g   f   c
0   -b  -e  -f  0   f   e   b
0   -a  -b  -c  0   c   b   a
```

Initialize the above matrix as:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   2   3   0   -3  -2  -1
0   2   4   5   0   -5  -4  -2
0   3   5   6   0   -6  -5  -3
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   -3  -5  -6  0   6   5   3
0   -2  -4  -5  0   5   4   2
0   -1  -2  -3  0   3   2   1
```

The DFT of this(B2D_7) matrix is obtained as:

```
fftwf_plan gplan_fw= fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(DFT_N, DFT_N, B2D_7, (fftwf_complex*)B2D_6_DFT, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftwf_execute(gplan_fw);
```

```
[0.000000]  [0.000000]      [0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [-81.597977]    [26.142136] [-9.999999] [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [26.142136]     [-4.000000] [2.142136]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [-10.000002]    [2.142135]  [-2.402020] [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [0.000000]      [0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [10.000002]     [-2.142135] [2.402020]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [-26.142136]    [4.000000]  [-2.142136] [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [81.597977]     [-26.142136][9.999999]  [0.000000]
```

We note here that this matrix has 0 imaginary component and odd-symmetry in y axis.

We now execute divergence_dft(B2D_6_DFT, B2D_6_DFT, DFT_N), with the same DFT matrix(seen above) for FDX and FDY:

```
static void divergence_dft  (float* const FDX, float* const FDY, cuint& N)
{
cfloat fM_PI= (float) M_PI;

cmplx *CMFDX= (cmplx*)  &FDX[0];
cmplx *CMFDY= (cmplx*)  &FDY[0];
const cmplx iota(0,1);

fComplx * const CFDX= (fComplx*) &FDX[0];
fComplx * const CFDY= (fComplx*) &FDY[0];

cfloat rcpL=1.f/N;
cfloat fN=(float) N;
cuint hNZ1 = N/2+1;
cuint hN = N/2;
cfloat fhN= (float) N/2;

uint i,j;

float fcX, fcY;
float nfcX=0.f, nfcY=0.f;

#define fPST 0.0f

for(j=0,fcY=fPST; j<N; ++j, fcY++ ){
    const uint idJ=(j*hNZ1);
    if (fcY<= fhN) nfcY=fcY; else nfcY=fcY-fN ;
                                                 

    for(i=0,fcX=fPST; i<hNZ1; ++i, ++fcX ){     
    const uint idc = i+idJ;


        cfloat kwtX=2.f*fM_PI*rcpL* fcX;
        cfloat kwtY=2.f*fM_PI*rcpL* nfcY;

        cmplx deltaFDX= CMFDX[idc] * iota* kwtX;
        cmplx deltaFDY= CMFDY[idc] * iota* kwtY;
        cmplx dotFD= (deltaFDX+deltaFDY);

        CFDX[idc].r = dotFD.real(); 
        CFDX[idc].i = dotFD.imag();
    

    }}


}
```

When we examine the output of divergence_dft, we notice that the symmetry in Y-axis has been lost. It complies with neither DST [0abc0-c-ba]  nor DCT [abcdedcb] pattern and we cannot apply either real transforms to invert the matrix:

```
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]      [0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [-0.000000, -128.173813 i]  [0.000000, 61.595959 i] [-0.000000, -31.415924 i]   [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 61.595959 i]     [-0.000000, -12.566371 i]   [0.000000, 8.412147 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [-0.000000, -31.415932 i]   [0.000000, 8.412146 i]  [-0.000000, -11.319254 i]   [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]      [0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, -15.707966 i]    [0.000000, 1.682429 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 20.531986 i]     [0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, -1.682429 i] [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
[0.000000, 0.000000 i]  [0.000000, 0.000000 i]      [0.000000, -20.531986 i]    [0.000000, 15.707962 i] [0.000000, 0.000000 i]
```